# Как сделать перенаравление?

Tags: html, .htaccess, html5

Привет. Необходимо сделать так, чтобы в адресной строке вместо localhost/_app/views/about.php был URL - http://localhost/about (желательно без расширения)
У меня в корне есть index.php, там же создана папка /_app/views/about.php.

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteRule ^about _app/views/about.php [L,QSA]
```

это в `.htaccess`

Comment: Cпасибо, очень помогли.

Comment: подскажите как сделать более универсальней, если я хочу у всех файлов в этой папке убрать .php? И проблема еще в том, что когда я добавляю слеш специально в конце, то происходит ошибка.